# Greatest possible height in tcbraster

Tags: tcolorbox, boxes, height

In the following situation, when the outer left box is higher than the outer right box, i want to have the greatest possible height for the inner boxes (inside the raster of the outer right box).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{%
    outer left/.style={frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=5pt, colback=yellow, halign=center, valign=center},
    outer right/.style={frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=2pt, colback=orange, halign=center, valign=center},
    inner right/.style={boxsep=3pt, halign=center, valign=center}
}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows, raster valign=center]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[outer left]
            w\\
            x\\
            y\\
            z
    \end{tcolorbox}
    %
    \begin{tcolorbox}[outer right]
        \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3]
            \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
                d
            \end{tcolorbox}
            %
            \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
                e
            \end{tcolorbox}
            %
            \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
                f
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{tcbraster}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have come up with a hacky solution (far from being perfect) that seems to work after two successive compilations.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{%
    outer left/.style={frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=5pt, colback=yellow, halign=center, valign=center},
    outer right/.style={frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=2pt, colback=orange, halign=center, valign=center},
    inner right/.style={boxsep=3pt, halign=center, valign=center, ht}
}

\makeatletter
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows, raster valign=center]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[outer left]
            w\\
            x\\
            y\\
            z
    \end{tcolorbox}
    %
    \begin{tcolorbox}[outer right,
            code={%
                    \edef\tcb@ehgid{\kvtcb@raster@ehgid @\number\c@tcbrasterrow}%
                    \ifcsundef{tcb@ehg@height@\tcb@ehgid}%
                        {\tcbset{ht/.style={}}}%
                        {%
                                \tcbheightfromgroup\myht{\tcb@ehgid}%
                                \tcbdimto\myresult{\kvtcb@top@rule@stand+\kvtcb@bottom@rule@stand+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@top+\kvtcb@bottom}%
                                \iftcb@hasTitle%
                                    \tcbdimto\myresult{\tcbtextheight+\ht\tcb@titlebox+\dp\tcb@titlebox+\kvtcb@title@rule+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@toptitle+\kvtcb@bottomtitle}%
                                \fi%
                                \tcbdimto\myresult{\myht-\myresult}%
                                \tcbset{ht/.style={height=\myresult}}%
                        }%
            }
]
        \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3]
            \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
                d
            \end{tcolorbox}
            %
            \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
                e
            \end{tcolorbox}
            %
            \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
                f
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{tcbraster}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]
But this solution requires me to delete the auxillary file and to recompile twice if any changes are made to the code (boxes content or settings like `boxsep` and so on).

Does anyone have a better solution? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution to my problem and it is based on the use of the `space to` key.

If it is tcolorbox included in the outer right box, we can use the `add to natural height` key.

On the other hand, if it is a raster, we will use the `height` key when the outer right box does not have its natural height (`\myspace>0pt`).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}


\begin{document}


\tcbset{%
    ht/.style={},
    outer left/.style={frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=5pt, colback=yellow, halign=center, valign=center},
    outer right/.style={frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=2pt, colback=orange, halign=center, valign=center},
    inner right/.style={boxsep=3pt, halign=center, valign=center, ht}
}

tcolorbox inside outer right box :

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows, raster  valign=center]
   \begin{tcolorbox}[outer left]
       w\\x\\y\\z
   \end{tcolorbox}
%
   \begin{tcolorbox}[outer right, space to=\myspace]
       \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right, add to natural height=\myspace]
         d
       \end{tcolorbox}
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows, raster valign=center]
   \begin{tcolorbox}[outer left]
       w
   \end{tcolorbox}
   %
   \begin{tcolorbox}[outer right, space to=\myspace]
       \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right, add to natural height=\myspace]
         d\\e\\f
       \end{tcolorbox}
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

tcbraster inside outer right box :

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows, raster valign=center]
   \begin{tcolorbox}[outer left]       
       w\\x\\y\\z
   \end{tcolorbox}
   %
   \begin{tcolorbox}[outer right, space to=\myspace]
       \ifdim\myspace>0pt\relax\tcbset{ht/.style={height=\myspace}}\fi%
       \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3]
           \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
               d
           \end{tcolorbox}
           %
           \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
               e
           \end{tcolorbox}
           %
           \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
               f
           \end{tcolorbox}
       \end{tcbraster}
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows, raster valign=center]
   \begin{tcolorbox}[outer left]
       w
   \end{tcolorbox}
   %
   \begin{tcolorbox}[outer right, space to=\myspace]
       \ifdim\myspace>0pt\relax\tcbset{ht/.style={height=\myspace}}\fi%
       \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3]
           \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
               d\\e\\f
           \end{tcolorbox}
           %
           \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
               f
           \end{tcolorbox}
           %
           \begin{tcolorbox}[inner right]
               g
           \end{tcolorbox}
       \end{tcbraster}
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]